# A place to store config file into google account

Tags: android

So, there is an app that is installed on more than one devices all connected to the same Google account. Suppose i want them to share a same config file or log file, so that every cellphone connected to the same Google account can read and write it. Is Mother Google offering a possibility to do it with her api? I was wondering about doing it on Google-docs, but i prefer this file to be hidden to the user, however any suggestion would be appreciated!